# Switch from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: spring, tomcat

I have a spring app running on tomcat and I've set up two connectors 8080 and 8443. I use 8443 for authentication and 8080 for the application. After authentication JSESSIONID is added with secure notation and thus it's not available in HTTP.

How can I create two types of authentication when authenticating with HTTPS so that HTTP would also be authenticated. I set my authentication with:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work out of the box. The session cookie that's set is shared for http & https. Examine the cookie and [verify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) if the domain, path & protocol are correctly set. Also you should verify your spring security configuration. Example [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/86982-configuration-for-applying-https-to-certain-pages)

Also you should really be using only https instead of serving any content through http - the overhead is insignificant while giving a big security benefit.

Answer (score 0):

**You can not do it and it has nothing to do with Tomcat.**

The issue is the browser will not send the same cookies that it was using for HTTPS to the HTTP URL. You will have to login twice. You could potentially do some very nasty things to somewhat accomplish this (like allowing session ids in the URL and/or some javascript to perform some autologin) but I highly recommend you do not do that.

The only solution I can see to make this work safely might be to use SAML single sign-on. Otherwise you really should serve everything you want authorization for under HTTPS (ie requires login).